# Deserialize JSON to a class (Newtonsoft, C#)

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I am trying to save JSON data into my Class. I've tried different ways but didn't succeed.
Here is my class:

```
class YoCurrency
{
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public double high { get; set; }
    public double low { get; set; }
    public double avg { get; set; }
    public double vol { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("vol_cur")]
    public double vol_cur { get; set; }
    public double last { get; set; }
    public double buy { get; set; }
    public double sell { get; set; }
    public int updated { get; set; }
}
```

Here is [JSON file.](https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/btc_usd-eth_usd-doge_usd-pac_usd-rdd_usd) 

Trying to deserialize with generic List:

```
List<YoCurrency> a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YoCurrency>>(json);
```

gives an error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[YoBitParser.YobitCurrency]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'btc_usd', line 1, position 11.'

Deserializing this way:

```
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YobitCurrency>(json);
```

Doesn't give any result, because all class fields get 0 value

Also I tried to use two classes like this:

```
class YoCurrency
{
    public double high { get; set; }
    public double low { get; set; }
    public double avg { get; set; }
    public double vol { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("vol_cur")]
    public double vol_cur { get; set; }
    public double last { get; set; }
    public double buy { get; set; }
    public double sell { get; set; }
    public int updated { get; set; }
}
class YoPair
{
    YoCurrency Currency { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But it didn't give any positive result. I tried to generate c# classes using http://json2csharp.com, but it generates a class for every currency:

```
public class BtcUsd
{
    public double high { get; set; }
    public double low { get; set; }
    public double avg { get; set; }
    public double vol { get; set; }
    public double vol_cur { get; set; }
    public double last { get; set; }
    public double buy { get; set; }
    public double sell { get; set; }
    public int updated { get; set; }
}

public class EthUsd
{
    ...
}
public class RootObject
{
    public BtcUsd btc_usd { get; set; }
    public EthUsd eth_usd { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

But i suppose it's not good way in case of 50 or 500 pairs (or should I create a unique class for every currency?)

So please help me to deserialize this JSON or give me some information that could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Paste your JSON for example into http://jsonviewer.stack.hu and see what object you get. Then deserialize it as you tried

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make one class?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var array = "[{\"btc_usd\":[{\"high\":8550.0102,\"low\":7800,\"avg\":8175.0051,\"vol\":1615543.57397705,\"vol_cur\":197.54076079,\"last\":7850,\"buy\":7850.00000000,\"sell\":7879.00000000,\"updated\":1521383863}],\"eth_usd\":[{\"high\":622.93708559,\"low\":482,\"avg\":552.46854279,\"vol\":346598.40520112,\"vol_cur\":630.37075493,\"last\":488.27857735,\"buy\":489.77564548,\"sell\":492.11726255,\"updated\":1521383876}]}]";
        List<RootObject> a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(array);
    }
}
public class RootCurrency
{
    public double high { get; set; }
    public int low { get; set; }
    public double avg { get; set; }
    public double vol { get; set; }
    public double vol_cur { get; set; }
    public double last { get; set; }
    public double buy { get; set; }
    public double sell { get; set; }
    public int updated { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<RootCurrency> btc_usd { get; set; }
    public List<RootCurrency> eth_usd { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like your class structure is not proper, suggest you to generate class with the help of Visual Studio like as below and try your code by using generated class

[image]

based on your json strucutre you need class design like this

```
public class Rootobject
{
   // do List<CurrencyDetail> if you are expecting multiple element
    public CurrencyDetail btc_usd { get; set; }
    public CurrencyDetail eth_usd { get; set; }
    public CurrencyDetail doge_usd { get; set; }
    public CurrencyDetail pac_usd { get; set; }
    public CurrencyDetail rdd_usd { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyDetail
{
    public float high { get; set; }
    public int low { get; set; }
    public float avg { get; set; }
    public float vol { get; set; }
    public float vol_cur { get; set; }
    public float last { get; set; }
    public float buy { get; set; }
    public float sell { get; set; }
    public int updated { get; set; }
}
```

my suggesting is if possible modify you json , which will contain currency type in currency detail than you class strucutre will be like

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public List<CurrencyDetail> currencies { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyDetail
{
    //btc_usd  or  eth_usd or doge_usd  or pac_usd 
    public string type { get; set; }
    public float high { get; set; }
    public int low { get; set; }
    public float avg { get; set; }
    public float vol { get; set; }
    public float vol_cur { get; set; }
    public float last { get; set; }
    public float buy { get; set; }
    public float sell { get; set; }
    public int updated { get; set; }
}
```